# Limit 1000 items query while paginating in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm making a Letter/pageNum pagination for my site, so that this way you can get into an index, and query for items that begin with the letter "A" and move between pages of registers that begin with the letter "A".

For this, I've created a python process executed in AWS Lambda that queries for these items, with a begins_with filter on a field, so that I can sort them out.

This process aims to query for (In example) 1000 items and keep the last evaluated key (if exists) to set it as exclusiveStartKey for the next page.

Let's imagine a letter "A" with 3 pages:

Page 1 has no exclusiveStartKey because I query for all registers that begin with the letter A.

Page 2 will have exclusiveStartKey taken from the query that has been done to get page 1 registers.

And so on...

This is gonna be used to limit between pages in real-time without losing any registers.

If a user asks me for the first page of the letter "A" I will query all items that exist between the first register of the letter "A" while gsi4sk is less than the second page's exclusiveStartKey's gsi4sk.

Same operation for Page 2, exclusiveStartKey taken from Page 1 query, while gsi4sk is less than Page 3 exclusiveStartKey's gsi4sk. If Page 3 does not exist, I will query all the items to the end.

I'm using boto3 from a lambda process, some code example can be this one:

```
if lastEvaluatedKey == "":
    response = ddb_client.query(
        TableName = singleTable,
        IndexName = "gsi4-index",
        KeyConditionExpression='gsi4pk = :gsi4pk and begins_with(gsi4sk, :gsi4sk)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':gsi4pk': gsi4pk,
            ':gsi4sk': gsi4sk
        },
        ProjectionExpression="pk, sk, gsi4pk, gsi4sk",
        Limit=current_limit
    )
else:
    response = ddb_client.query(
        TableName = singleTable,
        IndexName = "gsi4-index",
        ExclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey,
        KeyConditionExpression='gsi4pk = :gsi4pk and begins_with(gsi4sk, :gsi4sk)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':gsi4pk': gsi4pk,
            ':gsi4sk': gsi4sk
        },
        ProjectionExpression="pk, sk, gsi4pk, gsi4sk",
        Limit=current_limit
    )
```

This code queries up to ~200 registers when a current_limit is set to 1000.

Comment: Can you provide any details? What do you even use? AWS Console, AWS CLI, Python? What is your current code?

Comment: I agree @Marcin, added one example about the query I need to paginate

Comment: @Marcin I've updated the question explaining my use case as much as possible

Comment: @MarcosPérezFontecha A query can read up to 1MB. Is it possible it's returning only 200 items because it's hit that size limit? Note, it's not about the size of the data returned (e.g. your projection expression is presumably a subset of the total item attributes, which would reduce the size of the data returned) but about the items read, which would be the size of the (full) items matching your key conditions.